Which "big" language has a drastically different women's and men's speech? Does matriarchy slow down language change?
relations of sex and dialect to reduction 
Women's speech

Some linguists have suggested that women use more standard speech forms than men because they are more status-conscious than men. Women's speech also has less reduction.

Does a matriarchic society (or a society with very few male) slow down language change? or from the evidence available, it seems the effect is minimal as language contact, L2 speakers and social stability plays a much important role?
2.
Yanyuwu
Karaja
Here are two languages with a big difference in morphology/ phonology used in women's and men's speech.
Japanese has one of the biggest difference between women's and men's speech among all "big" languages (not tribal language). The difference is morphological, similar to the Yanyuwu example. eg. feminine verb/sentence ending/ particles and honorific speech (-zamasu/-kashira/-na no/ ara), a handful of gendered personal pronouns, (o-/go-) honorific noun prefix that sounds feminine.
Which "big" language has a similarly big difference between women's and men's speech?

Slavic languages don’t generally have men’s and women’s speech, do they? They obviously decline various things according to gender, but that only creates ‘gendered speech’ to the extent that a word is declined to modify the speaker, and this happens in most Indo-European (and Semitic) languages that have an opposition between masculine and feminine.

I don't speak any Slavic languages. I just know the family names are gendered. As far as I know, Hebrew and Arabic have gendered verb conjugation.

@Raxrax Gendered verb conjugation in that you indicate whether the noun doing the action is masculine or feminine, but that's not really about the gender of the person speaking except in first person singular verbs (which often don't have gender distinctions anyway—e.g. Akkadian has gender distinctions in the second and third person but not the first person).

Gendered family names are also quite common and not the same as gendered speech. Gendered speech generally refers to using different lexemes/forms based on the speaker’s sex/gender for things that don’t relate to the speaker. For example, if in the sentence “I saw the dog in the house” you would have to use different base words for ‘see’, ‘dog’ or ‘house’ depending on whether you’re a man or a woman, that’s gendered speech; but it wouldn’t count if it’s only ‘I’ that required different words, or if ‘saw’ took different personal suffixes, because those describe the speaker themself.

I've heard that it's often young women who are at the forefront of language change. Do you have anything in particular that suggests matriarchy would mean the opposite?

@curiousdannii from point 1. above and the paper "women's speech" in the link, women use more standard speech forms and women's speech has less reduction.

@Raxrax Standardizing speech is often the language change.

@curiousdannii it's a bit of both afaict. Women do tend to use forms from the prestige variety rather than local dialect forms, but when new innovations appear they are also generally ahead of the curve. One describes the situation in stable dialect contact, while the latter describes the situation as a given dialect undergoes change
